# How show image from bytes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, filecontentresult

Error

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The most appropriate method to
>   overload 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write
>   (System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

```
 @ImageResultHelper.Image<ShowcaseController>(c => c.FileContentResult(), 200, 50, "Current time")
```

and I need transmit new { bytes = item.ImageItems } to FileContentResult

Comment: We can't help unless you tell us more about it ...

Answer (score 4):

The way we do it, is we return a `FileContentResult`:

```
public FileResult Get()
{
    return new FileContentResult(image.Bytes, image.ContentType);
}
```

Then we set the src of the image to this action:

```
<img src="/Controller/Get/" alt="Whatever" />
```

This way you can cache the result.